# Default Values to Stored Procedure in Oracle

Tags: stored-procedures, parameters, plsql, oracle11g, default

I have a `stored procedure` as follows.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST(
       X IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'P',
       Y IN NUMBER DEFAULT 1) AS
 BEGIN
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('X'|| X||'--'||'Y'||Y);
 END;
```

When I execute the above procedure

```
 EXEC TEST(NULL,NULL);
```

It will print `X--Y`. The input parameters are not defaulting to the specified values in the procedure signature when input parameters are `null`. 
What is the use of `default` values then? What if we pass a `null` value as input and we want to replace a `null` value with the `default` value?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Default values are only used if the arguments are not specified. In your case you *did* specify the arguments - both were supplied, with a value of NULL. (Yes, in this case NULL is considered a real value :-). Try:

```
EXEC TEST()
```

Share and enjoy.

**Addendum**: The default values for procedure parameters are certainly buried in a system table somewhere (see the `SYS.ALL_ARGUMENTS` view), but getting the default value out of the view involves extracting text from a LONG field, and is probably going to prove to be more painful than it's worth. The *easy* way is to add some code to the procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST(X IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'P',
                                 Y IN NUMBER DEFAULT 1)
AS
  varX VARCHAR2(32767) := NVL(X, 'P');
  varY NUMBER          := NVL(Y, 1);
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('X=' || varX || ' -- ' || 'Y=' || varY);
END TEST;
```

Comment: Is there a way to check if the input value is null and replace it with default value?

Comment: See the addendum to my answer.

Answer (score 9):

Default-Values are only considered for parameters NOT given to the function.

So given a function

```
procedure foo( bar1 IN number DEFAULT 3,
     bar2 IN number DEFAULT 5,
     bar3 IN number DEFAULT 8 );
```

if you call this procedure with no arguments then it will behave as if called with

```
foo( bar1 => 3,
     bar2 => 5,
     bar3 => 8 );
```

but 'NULL' is still a parameter.

```
foo( 4,
     bar3 => NULL );
```

This will then act like

```
foo( bar1 => 4,
     bar2 => 5,
     bar3 => Null );
```

( oracle allows you to either give the parameter in order they are specified in the procedure, specified by name, or first in order and then by name )

one way to treat NULL the same as a default value would be to default the value to NULL

```
procedure foo( bar1 IN number DEFAULT NULL,
     bar2 IN number DEFAULT NULL,
     bar3 IN number DEFAULT NULL );
```

and using a variable with the desired value then

```
procedure foo( bar1 IN number DEFAULT NULL,
     bar2 IN number DEFAULT NULL,
     bar3 IN number DEFAULT NULL )
AS
     v_bar1    number := NVL( bar1, 3);
     v_bar2    number := NVL( bar2, 5);
     v_bar3    number := NVL( bar3, 8);
```