# ORACLE sql dynamic variables in stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

i want to add a variable to a stored procedure but i want to be able to run the stored procedure in one of 2 different ways:
- if it is null, then it runs everything otherwise just matching records
- if it is null, then make it default to a set value otherwise just matching records

```
var countyvar varchar2(50);
begin
if countyvar is null then 'yyyy';
end if;
end;
```

OR

```
var countyvar varchar2(50);
begin
if countyvar is null then run script for all locations;
if countyvar is 'yyyy' then run script for only that location;
end if;
end;
```

used here:

```
select locations, count(accountID) from dim_locations where location_name = :COUNTYVAR group by locations;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps you, but you can use the "DEFAULT" keyword in the procedure parameter declaration. For example:

```
PROCEDURE Get_emp_names (Dept_num IN NUMBER DEFAULT 20)
IS ...
```

And then you can control the flow of your procedure from inside. Just check if "countyvar" is null or not inside the procedure.

Check this also: [Default Values to Stored Procedure in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22544383/default-values-to-stored-procedure-in-oracle)

Comment: Only problem with that is the DEFAULT only works if you don't provide a parameter ... if you invoke:  `get_emp_names ( NULL )` ... it won't use 20 .. it'll use "NULL"  ;)  (that'll be the case if your passing a variable ... ie  `get_emp_names ( l_some_var )` ... and l_some_var happens to be NULL ...

Comment: I added a more detailed example showing this behaviour at the bottom of my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just do this ... watch for index performance however, it may or may not perform a little slower than expected depending on your data size and such ... test it out and tune a little as needed.

```
  select locations, count(accountID) 
    from dim_locations 
   where ( :COUNTYVAR IS NULL
          OR location_name = :COUNTYVAR )
   group by locations;
```

**[[Explanation of DEFAULT option mentioned in other answer ]]**

DEFAULT option only kicks in when the parameter is not provided, not when it's NULL ... here's a test sample showing the behaviour - try it out ;)

```
  set serverout on

  declare
     lv_var  varchar2(10);

     procedure p_test ( in_parm  IN  varchar2 default 10 )
     is
     begin
        dbms_output.put_line ( 'in_parm is: ' || nvl(in_parm,'<<NULL>>') );
     end;
  begin
     p_test ( 123 );
     p_test ();
     p_test ( NULL );
     lv_var := 234;
     p_test ( lv_var );
     lv_var := NULL;
     p_test ( lv_var );
  end;
  /

  in_parm is: 123
  in_parm is: 10
  in_parm is: <<NULL>>
  in_parm is: 234
  in_parm is: <<NULL>>
```

Comment: Yup, the first part worked perfectly. i was prompted to enter a value or leave it as NULL.

Comment: Yup, the first part worked perfectly; Ii was prompted to enter a value or leave it as NULL.

I adapted it as below and it compiles successfully
create or replace PROCEDURE PENETRATION_REPORT AS
COUNTYVAR VARCHAR2(25 CHAR);
TEXT VARCHAR2(40 CHAR);

IF (COUNTYVAR IS NULL) THEN TEXT := ' B.COUNTY IS NULL'; 
ELSE TEXT := ' B.COUNTY :=' || COUNTYVAR;
END IF;
But as I need to get to work in a table format, this is where it breaks down:

Comment: apologies for the edit issues as i did not realise there was a time limit to edit comments